How can I fix my loose Towel Hanger that is sliding down and making the bar fall
We have a towel hanger that is fitted to drywall.
It has two circular bases at edge and has a bar that joins these two bases to make a towel hanger. One of these bases is loose, so it slopes down making the cross bar to fall and hence not usable. After some Google searches, I saw that there is a screw below to tighten but this one has option for screw but Builder didn't put any screw. I have similar one in other Bathroom and its and there are no screws for them too.
Is there any easy way to remove the base or make it stand straight and not slope down?
These are Moen brand, but I couldn't find these Online to see if they have any manuals.
Reference pictures below:


=============================== Update =====================
I was able to find a suitable wrench screwdriver and was able to unscrew the Holder. Now i see the cause of the issue. The side that was loose was screwed in cross.
Refer the pictures below.


Is there a way to fix that one part of drywall or i have to remove and fix to a different spot?

In your picture from underneath, it looks like there's a hex set screw in there that can turn.  It won't be a typical screw that you could use a screwdriver on.  You'll need to find a hex (sometimes termed an Allen) wrench of the right size to fit in there and take the brackets off.
Most likely what happened is that the mounting plate that's actually attached to the wall has come loose from the wall and no longer is firmly attached.  My guess is that it was just drywall anchors and not driven into studs in the wall.  Very typical, and typically fails the same way yours did.
You'll need to take the brackets off first, then reattach the mounting plates with new drywall anchors firmly to the wall, then you can mount the brackets back onto the mounting plates.  But they key is to have the mounting plates firmly attached to the wall and not just with flimsy drywall anchors.

Thank you for update.. I have few Alan Wrench but they are bit bigger to pass thru. I will get smaller one this weekend and try to first take bracket out first.

I was not able to attach photo here so i have to add to main post.

I solved this problem with a toggle bolt to hold the mounting plate rather than the old drywall anchors.  The toggle requires a new large hole drilled with care.  Allow plenty of excess length of the bolt.    It is so strong that it is unlikely to be torn when someone puts more than a towel’s weight on it.   First, practice your technique on a scrap of half-inch drywall or other material.   I suggest a step drill bit for enlarging holes.

Step bits aren't going to be deep enough on each level to create a uniform bore in half inch drywall. Otherwise I agree.

While they practice on a scrap, they will find it helpful to make a hole accurately and they can finish it with alternative tools.  I would not try to make a neat hole in ragged drywall with other bits.   Also it takes a jab saw to make two grooves for the pin of the toggle.

I've always drilled a 3/8" hole with a standard high-speed steel bit and just wiggled the toggler through. Easy peasy.

Also if they want to drill into something irregular or crumbly with no good pilot hole, they can make an outside guide out of a scrap of wood with a hole through it, then hold it up to the work as a template and drill.  This helps very often with Forstner bits.

Late answer but literally just went through this at two rentals and my own house in last 3 months.   I have a question in the DIY sphere about it...
If you do not have wood to screw in behind the rack edge I would just suggest a plinth that is about the same size of the handle.    That is literally the only thing I could do without opening the wall and adding a 2x4 in.
So my answer is round rosette for towel bar or opening wall and adding framing to support the towel bar.   Otherwise you are spending more time asking for help vs just fixing it.
